# Removing various numbers and brackets

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I have various photo files, for example `DSC0001(0).jpg`, `DSC0002(3).jpg`, `DSC0003(13).jpg`.

How do I remove both brackets and numbers so that they will show as `DSC0001.jpg`, `DSC0002.jpg`, etc?

At the moment I've been using

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | foreach {
  Rename-Item $_ $_.Name.Replace("(0)", "")
}
```

and changing the number each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a RegEx match to do this with the `-Replace` operator.

```
GCI *.jpg|%{
    $NewName = $_.Name -replace '\(\d+\).jpg$','.jpg'
    $_|Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
}
```

To include things in subfolders:

```
GCI *.jpg -recurse |%{
    $NewName = $_.Name -replace '\(\d+\).jpg$','.jpg'
    $_|Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
}
```

To rename folders:

```
GCI *|Where{$_.PSIsContainer}|%{
    $NewName = $_.Name -replace '\(\d+\)$'
    $_|Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
}
```

Comment: I'm so new to this, what is regex, is it different to powershell?

Comment: RegEx is short for Regular Expressions. It is a method of performing pattern matching, lots of info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and this particular RegEx is explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/j0WspS/1).

Comment: I'd use `-Filter '*(*).jpg'`and directly pipe to Rename-Item `Get-ChildItem -Filter '*(*).jpg'|Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ' *\(\d+\).jpg$','.jpg'}`

Comment: My next question.. Is there a way of me performing this task on a folder with the files included as opposed to setting the location to each folder. For example I have to H:\User\Photos\Canon then H:\User\Photos\Sony for other folders, Can't I just go to H:\User\Photos and run this.

Comment: Yes, just add the -recurse switch

Comment: Errm, sorry to pester you, how would I do that? I think I'm way out of my depth in this subject.

Comment: If I wanted to apply this method to folders, what would be the extension, pictures or jpg, bmp etc, music is mp3, flac but what is it for folders?

Comment: There's a little more to it than that for folders, but not much. The first line becomes: `GCI * | Where{$_.PSIsContainer} |%` If this answer has solved your problem please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Where do I mark as accepted? I couldn't work out the folders one, could you should me an example? Basically I want to remove all _'s, how would I do that?

Comment: To the left of the answer there should be a checkmark to mark the answer as accepted. I updated to show recursive renaming, and how to rename folders.

Comment: Is there a way of renaming folders? I basically have folders named Marshmello_-_New_Single_-_Silent_feat._Khalid_Remixes_-_Joytime_Collective_RCA_Records, however I'd like to remove all of the _ from the text and replace them with a space.

Comment: Yeah, that's easy. `GCI * -Directory | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '_', ' '} -ea 0` That replaces all underscores with spaces in all folders in the current working directory. The `-ea 0` is short for `-ErrorAction Ignore`, so that folders that don't have an underscore don't throw errors since you'll be attempting to rename something to its same name.

Comment: Although this has worked for some files, it doesn't seem to have done anything to items in a bracket, is there something else I need to add?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: If I wanted to get rid of Brand_New_Single from a folder called Fuse_ODG_-_Brand_New_Single_-_'Only'_(Off_Da_Ground_3_Beat), it's throwing up an error as there are brackets.

Comment: But you aren't doing anything with the brackets... `$NewName = $_.Name -replace '-Brand_New_Single-' -replace '_', ' '`

Comment: Very odd, I thought the formula needed to be edited when working with () ' and []. I've noticed it works with some file/folder names but not with all, throws up and error.

Comment: When trying to remove _-_New_Single_-_ from Billon_-_New_Single_-_'Slave_To_The_Vibe'_(Remixes)_-_(Rinse_Virgin_EMI) I got the error

Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:20
+ ... Directory | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'New_Single', ' -  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\Winston\Musi...2003 (lossless):String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: Well, `-_New_Single-_` is different than `_-New_Single-_`, that could be the problem.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the wrong error, it changes all the filenames without brackets but shows errors for items in brackets.